# jQuery Ajax success function parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
  $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "contacts.php",  
            data: dataString,  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(data, status, settings)  
            {  
               alert(The request URL and DATA);
            }  
            ,
            error: function(ajaxrequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError)  
            {  

            }  
        });
```

How can I alert the The request URL and DATA parameters inside the Success function?

Thank You

Comment: "*How can I alert the The request URL and DATA parameters inside the Success function?"* FWIW, `alert`-style debugging went out of style at least five years ago, and certainly today there are *dramatically* better options. Every major browser offers a built-in debugger, and most of them are pretty good. You can put a breakpoint inside your `success` function, inspect the live data, single-step through your code, etc., etc. It's a much, *much* faster way to find bugs and such.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can simply;

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
   alert(this.data + "," + this.url); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Adapted from Alex K.'s answer, but using console.log instead:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
   console.log(this.data + "," + this.url); 
}
```

This will output the data to the debugging console instead of a modal dialog.

Answer (score 3):

I needed return some data in sucess response like:

Action (Rais):

```
  def comment
    comnent = AlarmComment.new alarm_id: params[:id],
                user_id:  current_user.id, comment: params[:comment]

    if comnent.save
      render json: comnent, status: :created
    else
      head status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

My Ajax (Coffee)

```
  $.ajax(
    url: "/alarms/#{alarm_id}/comment/"
    dataType: "json"
    method: "POST",
    data:
      comment: user_comment
  ).done( ->
    alert 'Comentário adicionado com sucesso'
  ).fail ->
    alert 'Erro ao adicionar'
```